# Uploadify: sending data with scriptData

Tags: php, uploadify

I want to send the session value with uploadify script. I'm tryin following in javascript:

```
 'scriptData': {'name':'<?php echo $_SESSION[name];?>'}
```

and in the php script im getting the value like:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

The script data returns the value `<?php echo $_SESSION[name];?>`
instead of getting the value stored in session, for example Peter. Can someone please tell me how can i fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try making a line above the javascript posted like: `var name = "<?=$_SESSION['name']?>";`

Comment: @0x90: I'm trying to send the session data directly with scriptData. Any idea?

Comment: This script is inside a php page, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
'scriptData': {'name':<?php echo "'".$_SESSION[name]."'";?>}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your are modifying a .js file instead of a .php file. So, a .js file will never execute php code (between  tags)